# Bootstrap form inputs aren't displaying correctly in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

On Internet Explorer, the form fields can be typed in but the types text isn't showing.

Here is the site in question: http://allaboutfreight.co.uk/samedaycourier.php

They display correctly in other browsers.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First of all: check the bootstrap issues [here](http://getbootstrap.com/browser-bugs/)

add the Respond.js and html5shiv scripts to your code if you don't have it yet (these two have been proven to solve a lot of issues for IE)

```
<script src="http://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="http://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
```

Also you have to add this tag to your header :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

This tag allows web authors to choose what Internet Explorer version the page should be rendered as hence the IE=edge in the content.

This might appear basic but sometimes people forget this tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
```